# Webpack: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename (Favicon)

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

The webpack is giving conflict error when building the project, the start server works normally.

I ended up discovering that the problem is in the "favicon" when creating the HTMLWebpackPlugin, it seems that because it contains more than one different .html with the same favicon it generates the conflict.

However, in the output I already inserted for the assets to come with hash and ext, but even so, nothing has changed.

What to do?

```
const getHTMLWebpackPlugin = filename => ({
    filename,
    template: PATH.resolve(__dirname, `src/pages/${filename}`),
    favicon: PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/images/logotype.webp"),
    chunks: "all",
    minify: true,
    cache: true,
    meta: {
        charset: "UTF-8",
        viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0",
        author: SITE_INFORMATION.AUTHOR,
        description: SITE_INFORMATION.DESCRIPTION,
        keywords: SITE_INFORMATION.KEYWORDS,
        robots: "index, follow",
        googlebot: "index, follow",
        "http-equiv": "X-UA-Compatible",
        "og:locale": "en_US",
        "og:type": "website",
        "og:url": SITE_INFORMATION.URL,
        "og:title": SITE_INFORMATION.TITLE,
        "og:site_name": SITE_INFORMATION.TITLE,
        "og:description": SITE_INFORMATION.DESCRIPTION,
        "og:image": SITE_INFORMATION.URL_IMAGE,
        "twitter:card": "summary_large_image",
        "twitter:url": SITE_INFORMATION.URL,
        "twitter:title": SITE_INFORMATION.TITLE,
        "twitter:description": SITE_INFORMATION.DESCRIPTION,
        "twitter:image": SITE_INFORMATION.URL_IMAGE,
        "twitter:image:alt": SITE_INFORMATION.TITLE,
        "theme-color": "#212529",
        "msapplication-TileColor": "#212529",
    },
});

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    target: "web",
    stats: {
        loggingDebug: ["sass-loader"],
    },
    devServer: {
        static: PATH.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: false,
        liveReload: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(getHTMLWebpackPlugin("index.html")),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(getHTMLWebpackPlugin("404.html")),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
            chunkFilename: "static/css/[id].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src/robots.txt"),
                    to: PATH.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
                    context: "*.txt",
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            "@assets": PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src", "assets"),
            "@pages": PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src", "pages"),
            "@scripts": PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src", "scripts"),
            "@scss": PATH.resolve(__dirname, "src", "scss"),
        },
    },
    output: {
        clean: !process.env.WEBPACK_SERVE,
        path: PATH.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js",
        chunkFilename: "static/js/[id].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js",
        assetModuleFilename: "static/assets/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]",
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: "deterministic",
        runtimeChunk: "single",
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all",
                },
            },
        },
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                minify: CssMinimizerPlugin.cleanCssMinify,
            }),
            new TerserPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
                parallel: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 8,
                    compress: {
                        ecma: 5,
                        warnings: false,
                        comparisons: false,
                        inline: 2,
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        safari10: true,
                    },
                },
            }),
            new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
                minimizer: {
                    implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.sharpMinify,
                    options: {
                        quality: 100,
                        encodeOptions: {
                            webp: {
                                lossless: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ttf)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(webp|ico)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /\.yaml$/i,
                type: "json",
                parser: {
                    parse: YAML.parse,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        cacheCompression: true,
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: { plugins: () => [AutoPrefixer()] },
                        },
                    },
                    { loader: "resolve-url-loader" },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```